# Sketch the Four Subspaces-Left Null space,null space,column space and row space?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a zero matrix both the null spaces are $0$ and column space and row space have zero has well. So how do I sketch this?

For an invertible matrix-the column space has $\Bbb R^m$ and the row space has $\Bbb R^n$ and the null space is zero. So how do I sketch this.

Comment: For the zero matrix the null space is obviously *not* $0$.

Comment: Oh my bad its not